# Im trying to understand "Getters" and "Setters" in the ruby programming language

Tags: ruby, setter, getter

Im currently doing some online tutorials about the ruby programming langauge and I think the explanations/examples I have been given thus far are lacking. I have two examples Id like to show you before directly asking the question.

The first example is:

**Traditional Getters/Setters;**

```
class Pen

  def initialize(ink_color)
    @ink_color = ink_color # this is available because of '@'
  end

  # setter method
  def ink_color=(ink_color)
    @ink_color = ink_color
  end

  # getter method
   def ink_color
    @ink_color
  end

end
```

And the second example is:

**ShortCutt Getter/Setters;**

```
class Lamp
  attr_accessor :color, :is_on

  def initialize(color, is_on)
    @color, @is_on = color, false
  end
end
```

Ok, So for the first example I think its pretty straight forward. I am 'initializing' an accessible variable throughout my entire Lamp class called "@ink_color". If I wanted to set "@ink_color" to red or blue I would simply call my 'Setter' method and pass 'red' or 'blue' to the parameter (ink_color) in my setter. Then If I wanted to access or 'Get/Getter' the color I have 'Set/setter' I would call my getter method and ask for 'ink_color'.

The second example makes sense to me as well; Instead of typing out what the getter and setter methods look like, ruby provides a 'shortcut' that essentially runs code to build the getter and setter for you.

But heres the question - How do I reverse engineer the 'shortcut' version? Lets say I was looking at my above shortcut example and wanted to do it the "traditional" way without a shortcut?

Would the reverse engineering of the "shortcut" look something like the below code(my attempt that doesn't seem right to me)....

**My Attempt/Example**

```
class Lamp

  def initialize(color, is_on)
    @color = color
    @is_on = is_on
  end

  def color=(color)
    @color = color
  end

   def is_on=(is_on)
    @is_on = is_on
  end

  def color
    @color
  end

  def is_on
    @is_on
  end

end
```

Is my attempt right/workable code? It just seems like im missing a piece conceptually when it comes to this getter/setter stuff.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what `attr_accessor` does.

Comment: "my attempt that doesn't seem right to me" - why does it not seem right to you?

Comment: Maybee its that im new to the language. I guess I should say : would 'My attempt' behave/execute the exact same way as the shortcut?

Comment: @Ghoyos Yes it would.

Comment: [`Module#attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

Comment: Try to avoid multi assignments like `x,y = a,b` because it can lead to some confusing ambiguity. One per line makes it abundantly clear what you're doing, and as a bonus, when you add or remove a line it is very clear in any diffs in your version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Understanding attr_accesor, attr_reader and attr_writer

These are Ruby's getters and setters shortcut. It works like C# properties, that injects the `get_Prop` (getter) and `set_Prop` (setter) methods.

- `attr_accessor`: injects `prop` (getter) and `prop=` (setter) methods.
- `attr_reader`: it's a shortcut for read-only properties. Injects `prop` method. The `prop` value can only be changed inside the class, manipulating the instance variable `@prop`.
- `attr_writer`: it's a shortcut for write-only properties. Injects `prop=` method.

Ruby doesn't have methods called `get_prop` (getter) and `set_prop` (setter), instead, they're called `prop` (getter) and `prop=` (setter).

That being said, you can infer that

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end
```

is the short version for

```
class Person
  # getter
  def name
    return @name
  end

  # setter
  def name=(value)
    @name = value
  end
end
```

You don't need to call `return`, Ruby methods returns the last executed statement.

If you are using Ruby on Rails gem, you can build model objects using `new` and passing properties values as arguments, just like:

```
p = Person.new(name: 'Vinicius', age: 18)
p.name
=> 'Vinicius'
```

That's possible because Rails injects something like this `initialize` method to `ActiveRecord::Base` and classes that includes `ActiveModel::Model`:

```
def initialize(params)
  params.each do |key, value|
    instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: _If you are using Ruby on Rails gem, you can build any object using new and passing properties_ - I don't think that's true. A class must extend `ActiveRecord::Base` or include `ActiveModel::Model` to get that behaviour.

Comment: The `return` here is already implicit and doesn't really add clarity, but instead draws unnecessary attention to itself.

Comment: It's worth noting that the actual ActiveRecord implementation doesn't use attributes like this per-se, but a more complex system that tracks changes to attributes and can differentiate between expressions of data via methods and the raw database values.